# API consumer & data conversion

Tags: javascript, api

I'm building a JS web application that, essentially, consumes the data of various APIs. Some of these APIs use MySQL and PHP, so to avoid floating point inaccuracy issues, it converts all currency data to integer values (*by multiplying the provided data by 100, for example*). When I fetch that data, I re-convert it to its local representation by dividing by 100.

simple.

My question is more in regards to flow & best-practice:
**Where/when should the data conversion occur in the application?**

The two possibilities I've come up with are the following:

1. Immediately convert at the doorway between application and api, i.e. just before POST or PUT, I adjust to the API's expected format. Right after GET, I convert to my expected local format. *this method seems nice as I have a single point of conversion*
2. Make the conversion just before injecting data into a VIEW (*rendering*). This feels better because I then work in the API format (*and avoid floating-point inaccuracy issues*) all the way until I need to display data.

For most of the manipulations I make, floating-point inaccuracy isn't really an issue. But I've always been told to not wait for that to bite me in the a**.

In any case, I'm looking for feedback from people who have tried either method, and the relative pros/cons they've had with those methods.

thank you

Comment: Is the question missing any explanations?

Answer (score 1):

> floating point inaccuracy issues

This sounds like inter-protocol data serialization problem and therefore I vote for your #1 option. All protocol-related data conversions should be performed as close as possible to the protocol level.